# Software to to work with band practice

Tags: pm-software, communication

Is there any software, preferably web based, that will allow a small group of people, a band, to communicate easily, share song lists and songs, and notes?

The song list is simply a list of songs with some information. Excel can represent it quite easily but it would be nice to have SVN like characteristics(so modifications can be made but reverted if necessary) and the ability to view as pdf.

It should be easy enough to for non-tech savy people to use it(but of course be able to surf the web, etc...). That is, no software to install(or very few dependencies) and no technical jargon needed to use... minimal interface, etc.

The idea is to get away from email which can be a hassle to manage and move on to something that is more centralized.

Anything like this exists?

Comment: Try asking on superuser.com

Comment: I can see how this "might" be considered on-topic here. Band practice might not fall into traditional project management, but the communication challenges the op faces are something many PM's face. Therefore, it's up to the 500+ rep users on this site to decide if it's not an on-topic question.

Answer (score 3):

I think that all the features you're looking for are available in Google Docs:

- Simple UI
- Collaborative editing
- Revision history
- Save as PDF

... and it's free!

Comment: I've used this before for other projects but it's a but to "computer programmer'ish".

Answer (score 0):

Check out [basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/) from [37Signals](http://37signals.com)

Comment: It's not too bad. It has basic features that are useful and might be what I need. The free version's 10MB upload is a bit low and probably the biggest issue I have as I would like to upload some audio. It's not a big deal to get around but 24$ a month for the most basic version is a bit too much for what it offers.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is launching 60 new apps now a day (really, I checked it twice typing "Facebook news" in Yahoo). Maybe not 60 as of today, but there are major innovations comming from the Facebook team soon that will happily surprise many Facebook users. They pushed Facebook to a new level keeping Mister Mark Zuckerberg initial vision to built a more opened and connected world. A great success to my point of view. Maybe some of those new applications (like Tickect Master for example) will help you and your band members to get your talent and dreams noticed more quickly and efficiently. Maybe you could have also a public page were your fans could click "like" and interact with them. You can even post your own publicity on the Facebook site. It is easy and fast. I am sure most Facebook users are in your "market" (pardon me that expression). You can adapt who will view it, depending how much you are willing to invest, etc. You will have a great impact with minimal cost. Do not miss your great opportunity if it fits with your own philosophy and dreams. But Facebook is a tool that can be adapted to any situation to my point of view.

Comment: Can you provide a specific Facebook app that will help this user?  I'm afraid your answer might be a little too vague to be helpful, as an actual answer, as opposed to a comment.

Comment: Ticketmaster for example; I was not only talking about apps and making music, but having a public page; publicity; fans; etc. I will give more details the next time. Thanks

Comment: Hi Simon, welcome to PMSE! One of the cool things about the SE sites is you can always edit and improve an answer. (You should see an "edit" link underneath your answer).  It's not that what you've written is "bad" necessarily, it's just that as-is, most community members would probably agree it's a better "helpful comment" than an actual answer. Most people here are also really nice + will help guide you if they see that you're new to the network. I encourage you to continue to participate and share your knowledge :)  Again, welcome to PMSE!

Comment: I have a great hability to summarise and make thing appear simple; maybe that is why I earned the badje of a teacher. I do not like to go in management books anymore; I trust my instinct better. But I will be more specific from now on and edit my answers if needed. Thanks